# Can i use spring bean at different places or at one place

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Suppose i have this in controller

```
@Resource(name="registrationService")
private RegistrationService registrationService;
```

This is working fine and i can use methods in service class.

Now suppose i have different  java class and i want to use methods in registrationService class . so can i use same thing there

```
@Resource(name="registrationService")
private RegistrationService registrationService;
```

and access methods or i have to declare different bean in spring with different name

This is the function in Service class

```
public String test(){   return "testing"; }
```

Now if i call this in controller , it works fine .

But i have separate class called UserDAO for getting users.
If i do like this

private List internalDatabase() {

```
        List<Registration> users = new ArrayList<Registration>();
        Registration user = null;

            logger.debug("Before");
    logger.debug(registrationService.test());
    logger.debug("After");

            users.add(user);
        return users;
    }
```

Anything after

```
logger.debug(registrationService.test());
```

is not executed . if i remove that line everything works . i don't know whats the problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Spring to inject the same bean into two different classes.

Comment: i have simple function in Service class which is executing properly in one controller but not in other class. i will put in question

Answer (score 0):

my best guess is a NullPointerException occured on

```
 logger.debug(registrationService.test());
```

that's why the succeeding lines wasn't executed. registrationService, i believe wasn't properly injected by the container. Make sure that your service class is either properly defined on your applicationContext.xml or the package is included on the component scanning.

Make sure also that UserDAO is managed by Spring or has a way (if not) to access your spring-managed service class.

Comment: Your controller class is  managed by Spring that's why it was able to inject your service class. Your DAO probably, wasn't.

Comment: i am using this tutorial http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration_18.html , Can you please tell me how can i inject UserDAO via spring in it

Comment: You are creating an instance of  UserDAO via the new keyword. You can use Spring's @Configurable annotation. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable to make Spring manage your object. According to Spring docu, "As a result, any time you instantiate an object, Spring will attempt to perform dependency injection on that object. This occurs for instantiation via the "new" keyword, as well as via reflection. In effect this feature allows dependency injection of any object at all in your system, which is a very useful feature.